# Swift Quiz App option Button background change

Tags: swift, uibutton

My Model :

```
struct MotorModel : Codable {
    let q : String
    let a : [String]
    let correctAnswer : String
}
```

And QuizBrain :

```
struct QuizBrain : Codable {
    
    var questionNumber = 0
    
    var quiz = [
        
        MotorModel(q: "Aşağıdakilerden hangisi araçta fazla yakıt tüketimine sebep olur?", a: ["A) Bujilerin yeni olması","B) Yakıt borularının uzun olması","C) Depodaki yakıt seviyesinin düşmesi","D) Tavsiye edilmeyen araç lastiği kullanılması"], correctAnswer: "D) Tavsiye edilmeyen araç lastiği kullanılması"),

 MotorModel(q: "Benzinli motorlar hangi prensibe göre çalışır?", a: ["A) Sıkıştırılmış hava üzerine mazot püskürtme","B) Sıkıştırılmış mazot-hava karışımını bujiyle ateşleme","C) Sıkıştırılmış benzin-hava karışımını bujiyle ateşleme","D) Sıkıştırılmış benzin-hava karışımını enjektörle ateşleme"], correctAnswer: "C) Sıkıştırılmış benzin-hava karışımını bujiyle ateşleme")
}
```

My answer func :

```
  func checkAnswer(userAnswer : String)-> Bool {
        if userAnswer == quiz[questionNumber ].correctAnswer {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

my answer to the question on the screen :

```
  @objc func TappedButton(_ sender : UIButton){
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        
        let userRightGot = quizBrains.checkAnswer(userAnswer: userAnswer)
        
        
        if userRightGot {
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
            
            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        }else{
            
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
            
            
            failScore += 1
            failScoreLabel.text = "\(failScore)"
        }
}
```

When I click on the wrong option I want to do here, the background picture of the correct answer is green.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oMyC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `TappedButton(_ sender: UIButton)` function will be called when the user taps on a button. The `sender` is the specific `UIButton` the user pressed.

If you want to change background color of other buttons, like the correct button if the user selects the wrong option, you will need to have a reference to that button with an `@IBOutlet` variable and change its color manually. This will require some logic to determine which button is the "correct" button.

Comment: i'm new to swift. Would you do this for me? thanks